# Duplicate JWT tokens when generated quickly

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a problem with duplicate JWT tokens when the tokens are generated quickly after each other. I discovered the issue when I was testing my /auth endpoint. When sending two requests quickly after each other, I can often get two HTTP responses containing the exact same JWT access token. I am also able to reproduce the issue when calling the JWT generate method in a loop. Getting duplicate JWT tokens when calling the token generate method inside a loop is something I can somewhat understand, but getting the same token in between two HTTP requests seems unacceptable to me?

Pasting my entire JWT generator class would be somewhat big, so I found this piece of code online which is pretty much what my class boils down to and yields the same result. Duplicate JWT tokens when called too quickly after each other.

So am I missing something here? Why am I getting duplicate JWT tokens or is this by design?

```
public bool ValidateCurrentToken(string token)
{
var mySecret = "asdv234234^&%&^%&^hjsdfb2%%%";
var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySecret));

var myIssuer = "issuer";
var myAudience = "myaudience";

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
try
{
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = myIssuer,
        ValidAudience = myAudience,
        IssuerSigningKey = mySecurityKey
    }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: I recon the token is only the same if the token content is the same. Are you sure this is a problem, because if user A (or system A) logs in, it doesn't really matter if the token is the same, for the same user, right?

Comment: Good point, haven't thought about that. So the token will always be the same if all the content is the exact same. So when the HTTP request was quick enough to respond twice within the same second, all the token parameters are identical. The thing is, I am storing SHA hashes from the tokes in the database, so I can invalidate them if the user wants to. And I don't want duplicate entries in the database.

Comment: That's understandable, but the scenario is still unlikely. And if it is stored for invalidation - you can argue both tokens should become invalid, hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue I handled by adding a `new Claim("Instance", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())`

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                        //Other claims ......
                        //Other claims ......
                        new Claim("Instance", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())

                    }),
                    Issuer = issuer,
                    Expires = 10,
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, the problem is due to the `iat` and `eat` attributes of the token.

This behavior is by design, if you don't change the contents of a token they'll indeed look the same. In this situation, this is probably happening because the "issued at" and "expired at" by default are precise only to the second.

This means that if you generate two tokens in the same "second", the tokens will look exactly the same (assuming that their contents and secrets are the same).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

JWTAuthenticationIdentity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Infrustructure.Security
{
    public class JWTAuthenticationIdentity : GenericIdentity
    {

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public JWTAuthenticationIdentity(string userName)
            : base(userName)
        {
            UserName = userName;
        }


    }
}
```

AuthenticationModule.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Infrustructure.Security
{
    public class AuthenticationModule
    {
        private const string communicationKey = "AGUS#@Sjfuy!@#zxcFSLKIWMDSDHJS87MCJWssd$#@kkx";
        SecurityKey signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(communicationKey));


        // The Method is used to generate token for user
        public string GenerateTokenForUser(string userName, int userId,string role)
        {


            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(communicationKey));
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey,
               SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,role)
            });

            var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Audience="OstadHamrah",
                IssuedAt = DateTime.Now,
                Issuer = "kimya",
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);

            return signedAndEncodedToken;

        }

        /// Using the same key used for signing token, user payload is generated back
        public JwtSecurityToken GenerateUserClaimFromJWT(string authToken)
        {

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {

                ValidAudience = "OstadHamrah",

                ValidIssuers = new string[]
                  {
                      "kimya",
                  },
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            SecurityToken validatedToken;

            try
            {

                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;

            }

            return validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken;

        }

        public JWTAuthenticationIdentity PopulateUserIdentity(JwtSecurityToken userPayloadToken)
        {
            string name = ((userPayloadToken)).Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type == "unique_name").Value;
            string userId = ((userPayloadToken)).Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type == "nameid").Value;
            return new JWTAuthenticationIdentity(name) { UserId = Convert.ToInt32(userId), UserName = name };

        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you